# Confused about HashMap in Java8

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8

I have a hashmap that takes String and HashSet as key and values.
I am trying to update the map and add values in it.

I cannot understand which of the following methods to use-

1. `map.putIfAbsent(str.substring(i,j),new HashSet<String>).add(str);
   //this method gives nullpointerexception`
2. `map.computeIfPresent(str.substring(i,j),(k,v)->v).add(str);`

In the output I can see the same key being added twice with an initial value and updated value.

Someone please tell me how to use these methods.

Comment: What is the NPE coming from? Is it the `str`, the `map` or the return of `putIfAbsent`?

Comment: A quick glance at the javadoc says that `putIfAbsent` returns a null when that key is not yet in the map. Did you consider that possibility before calling add()?

Comment: Why do you think, you have to choose between these two methods? There are at least four methods for this purpose, not counting the inappropriate one you listed.

Answer (score 4):

The preferable way to do it is with [`Map#computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-). This way a new `HashSet` is not created unnecessarily, and it will return the value afterwards.

```
map.computeIfAbsent(str.substring(i, j), k -> new HashSet<>()).add(str);
```

Comment: This would solve your problem.  `putIfAbsent` returns a null if the key didn't exist already in the map, so there is the possibility of the NPE.  `computeIfAbsent` only returns null if they key didn't exist AND the passed in value supplier returns a null, which it won't, since it is a constructor call.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to choose between `putIfAbsent` and `computeIfPresent`. Most notably, `computeIfPresent` in entirely inappropriate as it, as its name suggests, only computes a new value, when there is already an old one, and `(k,v)->v` even makes this computation a no-op.

There are several options

1. `containsKey`, `put` and `get`. This is the most popular pre-Java 8 one, though its the most inefficient of this list, as it incorporates up to three hash lookups for the same key

   ```
   String key=str.substring(i, j);
   if(!map.containsKey(key))
       map.put(key, new HashSet<>());
   map.get(key).add(str);
   ```
2. `get` and `put`. Better than the first one, though it still may incorporate two lookups. For ordinary `Map`s, this was the best choice before Java 8:

   ```
   String key=str.substring(i, j);
   Set<String> set=map.get(key);
   if(set==null)
       map.put(key, set=new HashSet<>());
   set.add(str);
   ```
3. `putIfAbsent`. Before Java 8, this option was only available to `ConcurrentMap`s.

   ```
   String key=str.substring(i, j);
   Set<String> set=new HashSet<>(), old=map.putIfAbsent(key, set);
   (old!=null? old: set).add(str);
   ```

   This only bears one hash lookup, but needs the unconditional creation of a new `HashSet`, even if we don’t need it. Here, it might be worth to perform a `get` first to defer the creation, especially when using a `ConcurrentMap`, as the `get` can be performed lock-free and may make the subsequent more expensive `putIfAbsent` unnecessary.

   On the other hand, it must be emphasized, that this construct is not thread-safe, as the manipulation of the value `Set` is not guarded by anything.
4. `computeIfAbsent`. This Java 8 method allows the most concise and most efficient operation:

   ```
   map.computeIfAbsent(str.substring(i, j), k -> new HashSet<>()).add(str);
   ```

   This will only evaluate the function, if there is no old value, and unlike `putIfAbsent`, this method returns the new value, if there was no old value, in other words, it returns the right `Set` in either case, so we can directly `add` to it. Still, the `add` operation is performed outside the `Map` operation, so there’s no thread safety, even if the `Map` is thread safe. But for ordinary `Map`s, i.e. if thread safety is not a concern, this is the most efficient variant.
5. `compute`. This Java 8 method will always evaluate the function and can be used in two ways. The first one

   ```
   map.compute(str.substring(i, j), (k,v) -> v==null? new HashSet<>(): v).add(str);
   ```

   is just a more verbose variant of `computeIfAbsent`. The second

   ```
   map.compute(str.substring(i, j), (k,v) -> {
       if(v==null) v=new HashSet<>();
       v.add(str);
       return v;
   });
   ```

   will perform the `Set` update under the `Map`’s thread safety policy, so in case of `ConcurrentHashMap`, this will be a thread safe update, so using `compute` instead of `computeIfAbsent` has a valid use case when thread safety is a concern.

Comment: Would a thread safe multimap also need the inner collections to be thread safe anyway? Otherwise, the state of the collection returned by  `get` operations wouldn't be thread safe, because the map doesn't give any wrapper to the values it stores.

Comment: Do you have a particular “thread safe multimap” implementation in mind? Generally, if the value handed out by a thread safe map is mutable, there has to be another policy regarding how to ensure the thread safety of the value. It doesn’t have to be the collection itself implementing the policy, but all threads accessing it must obey it.

Comment: I was thinking of an implementation that used [a new set created this way](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#newKeySet--), so that the values have a concurrent backing. That's a good point though, depending on if `compute` or `computeIfPresent` is the only way values are mutated, there would be thread safety.

Comment: @4castle: well, at some point, the values have to be read. But if the application has a logic that ensures that the values are only read after the completion of all mutating tasks or when it uses one of the new bulk processing methods of `ConcurrentHashMap`, it will not need additional thread safety for the value types.